# How to show view controller for 4 seconds after user select the raw in didSelectRowAt method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

I have one view controller with table view. I want know, how it possible to make, that when user tap on one of the row it will show another view controller for 5 seconds. Here is my code. I've created a objc func:

```
@objc func moveHome() {
        store.dispatch(NavigationAction(destination: .home, direction: .forward))
    }
```

And in the method didSelectRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let st = UIStoryboard(name: "SchoolsMain", bundle: nil)
        let vc = st.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchoolsPreHomeViewController") as? SchoolsPreHomeViewController
        UserDefaults.standard.set(testData[indexPath.row].name, forKey: "orgNameForSplash")

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.moveHome), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
```

It's works, but not like I want. Now when we select each of the row, we waiting for 5 seconds and then another view controller shows. But I want that we tap and it will show at the moment for 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you want to **present** `SchoolsPreHomeViewController`? Or, is your table view in a navigation controller and you want to **push** it?

Comment: I want to show it like splash screen and after this go to another view controller

Comment: That's a confusing description... When you select a row, you want to, what, show a **full-screen view** for 5 seconds? Then, you want to *"go to another view controller"* ... What does "go to" mean? Are you in a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let st = UIStoryboard(name: "SchoolsMain", bundle: nil)
    gaurd let vc = st.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchoolsPreHomeViewController") as? SchoolsPreHomeViewController else {
        return
    }
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    // or you can push it to the navigation controller
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // if you have pushed the vc on navigation stack then pop it here
    }

}
```

Comment: So after dismiss I can show another view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Set the timer of 5 seconds in the ViewController (SchoolsPreHomeViewController) that you need to show and on the completion of those 5 seconds call the method in which you will need to write the code to dismiss/pull it (SchoolsPreHomeViewController).

Feel free to ask if any doubt.

**Latest Edit SchoolsPreHomeViewController.swift**

```
class SchoolsPreHomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer: Timer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(moveHome), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    @objc func moveHome() {
        // Assuming your desired view controller is in 'SchoolsMain' storyboard and its class name is 'HomeViewController'
        let st = UIStoryboard(name: "SchoolsMain", bundle: nil)
        let vc = st.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like this in schoolsprehomeviewcontroller, but it's not working:     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        SchoolsPreHomeViewController.screenPresnted = true
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(moveHome), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    @objc func moveHome() {
        store.dispatch(NavigationAction(destination: .appHome, direction: .forward))
    }

Comment: Instead of 'store.dispatch(NavigationAction(destination: .appHome, direction: .forward))' you can try 'self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)' in your moveHome() function.

Comment: I've tried and it taking me back to the view controller where did select row

Comment: Oh okay, so to which view controller do you want to navigate?

Comment: I want that user select the row it should show splash screen with schoolsprehomeviewcontroller and the go to another

Comment: Hey @dextermikles, I have edited my answer as per your requirement. Please try that and let me know if any doubt.

Comment: I've tried your update and it's still getting me back to view controller with didselectrow. Do we need this popviewcontroller method?

Comment: Okay, so if you don't need to get back to the previous view controller then write the code to navigate to the desired controller in moveHome() function of 'SchoolsPreHomeViewController'. Also, it would be helpful if you can provide how you are trying to navigate to your desired view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240592/discussion-between-raj-pahelajani-and-dextermikles).